# SVG image center in col-lg but not col-xs in bootstrap4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to my SVG image should be come in right of col-lg but center in col-xs (Mobile version) in boottrap4.

This is my code which is written by me.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div style="border:1px solid #cc0000;" class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 float-left text-lg-right text-sm-center"><img src="nps-icon.svg" alt="Net Promoter Score" width="175" height="150" /></div>
<div style="border:1px solid #cc0000;" class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 float-left text-lg-right"><img src="nps-icon.svg" alt="Net Promoter Score" width="175" height="150" /></div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no `col-xs` in Bootstrap 4, if you aren't of course using an (ancient) alpha version of it. It is now just `col`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
so how can i center this images in mobile version with the use of bootstrap4

Comment: How about adding the classes `float-right float-sm-none` to your image tags?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `text-sm-center`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div style="border:1px solid #cc0000;" class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 float-left text-lg-right text-sm-center"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/Firefox_Logo%2C_2017.svg" alt="Net Promoter Score" width="175" height="150" /></div>
    <div style="border:1px solid #cc0000;" class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 float-left text-lg-right text-sm-center"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/Firefox_Logo%2C_2017.svg" alt="Net Promoter Score" width="175" height="150" /></div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/Pai1Qzexec

Comment: Sorry friend not working it is working only sm device not in mobile line below 576 width